# Reduce the quantity from the main table

Tags: php, html

When inserting details to a sub table, i want to reduce that amount from the main table. For example, if the main table has 10 items, i reduce 6 items via a form, and when i submit it, the main table should have 4 from that item.
my main table is **mainstock** and the sub table is **request**
this is my code.

```
[![<form id="details" action="" method="POST">
        <label for="Item">Item</label>
        <select id="Item" name="Item">
            <option value="item one">One</option>
            <option value="item two">Two</option>
            <option value="item three">Three</option>
        </select>
        <label for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
        <input type="text" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" placeholder="Enter the Quantity">
        <label for="Location">Location</label>
        <select id="Location" name="Location">
            <option value="item one">One</option>
            <option value="item two">Two</option>
            <option value="item three">Three</option>
        </select>
        <label for="FromDate">From</label>
        <input <label type="text" id="FromDate" name="FromDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
        <label for="ToDate">To</label>
        <input <label type="text" id="ToDate" name="ToDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">

        <center><button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button onclick="win();" name="Back" type="back" id="details-back">Back</button></center>
    </form>

<!-- INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE -->
<?php

    if(isset($_POST\['submit'\])){


    $Item = $_POST\['Item'\];
    $Quantity = $_POST\['Quantity'\];
    $Location = $_POST\['Location'\];
    $FromDate = $_POST\['FromDate'\];
    $ToDate = $_POST\['ToDate'\];

    //Insert Query of SQL
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO request(Item,Quantity,Location,FromDate,ToDate) VALUES ('$Item','$Quantity','$Location' ,'$FromDate', '$ToDate')",$connection);
    }

?>          
<!-- END INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE       -->]
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you break it down? Where's your **mainstock**?

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to MySQL injection, you're also using a deprecated function. Please move over to using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: "mainstock" and "request" are database tables

Answer (score 0):

You have the quantity at hand, so you can update mainstock:

```
UPDATE `mainstock` SET `quantity`=`quantity` - '.$Quantity.' WHERE `item`="'.$Item.'"'
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to update the quantity in mainStock table after insertion into request table.

For this you can execute a select & update query on main table.

for example =>

//select query

```
$query = mysql_query("select Quantity from mainstock where Item = '$Item'"),$connection)
```

Once you have the current value of quantity, you can calculate remaining.

```
$remaining = $current - $Quantity;
```

//update main table using update query

```
$query = mysql_query("update mainstock SET Qauantity = '$remaning' where Item = '$Item'"),$connection);
```

Hope this helps :)